# Would the post office really deliver Santa Claus's mail to some guy claiming to be him?

Tags: plot-explanation, miracle-on-34th-street

A key scene in "Miracle on 34th Street" involves the US Post Office delivering -- to a man in a courtroom for a hearing regarding his sanity, who claims to be Santa Claus -- hundreds of kids' letters addressed to Santa Claus, without a valid mailing address (because ****SPOILER*** Santa Claus does not really exist).

In real life, would the US Post Office really hand over children's mail to a man claiming to be Santa Claus, particularly in a courtroom setting?

Comment: The _United States Postal Service_ has a __[Letters to Santa](http://about.usps.com/corporate-social-responsibility/letters-to-santa.htm#p=1)__ program (also known as [Operation Santa](http://about.usps.com/corporate-social-responsibility/faqs.htm#p=1)), which started in 1912.

Answer (score 2):

In principle, the answer is "yes" but not in the way that you mean. The USPS operates a scheme known as '[Letters to Santa](http://about.usps.com/corporate-social-responsibility/letters-to-santa.htm#p=1)' in which members of public can agree to adopt letters that are addressed to Santa Claus or Father Christmas (e.g. without a valid address). These letters can then be responded to with the *requested* gift and a brief letter in response.

There's no obvious legal impediment to one individual offering to accept ***every single letter*** although it would be unlikely that the USPS would actually agree to do this unless they were 100% certain that the recipient could realistically afford to give a gift to every letter they accepted.